# Very frustrated about android debugging mode and reading output in logcat

Tags: android, debugging, emulation, adb, mode

this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow.
I'm working on a small app on android just for fun over the school break. My app is working fine and displays logcat just fine when I am running it on emulator. But when everytime I try to run the app on my phone through debugging bridge, logcat never displays at all. I've tried every methods that I was able to find on google including:

1. going into ddms and selecting my device
2. using adb logcat -d foo:D *:S  which only displays
   --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
   --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
3. etc

I remember it was working fine quite a while ago but since i have changed to my brand new computer it just don't work anymore. Please help :( im stuck here for like 3 hours now

thank you guys =)

Comment: Sounds like problem with drivers if it's only happening with the new pc...

Comment: you can restart your adb

Comment: try running adb devices command, does it show your device in that list

Comment: sorry Rinkalkumar, it took me some time to figure out how to replay :). yes it lists my device when i run that command

Comment: Thanks for reply Nuno, it might be reason for the driver but running app as debugging mode is working fine right now, except displaying logcat :( i'm really unhappy about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved the issue by using Log.e instead of other log levels. This took me so long time to figure it out, i've reinstalled my eclipse and adb but it didn't help at all.
I don't know if this is just for me but i hope this helps for some of you who are having same trouble as me

use Log.e !!

Answer (score 0):

Try some tricks below

Sometimes phone is not recognized by the driver. Run

- sudo ./adb kill-server
- sudo ./adb start-server

Update ddms, the latest ones are good, and there are fixes for many issues

Run ddms from command line, the one in eclipse is not as good as the command line one.

Comment: i've typed in adb kill-server and adb start-server in my platform-tools folder but logcat still doesn't display anything. Did i do it right anyways? I'm using windows

Comment: I dont know dude, Can you check your driver. Or another phone. That way you can zero down to a phone/driver combination.

Answer (score 0):

We cant exactly predict what may be the problem , but try these methods which may workout sometime.

*Use the command adb remount

*select the device within which select your application process

*Use the TAG for your logs and create new filter with that log name.

*Click between your filter and All messages in Log cat.

*Try re connecting the device again.

If still there is problem then please share more information.